# How do I convert data from a custom editor to a static data structure for use in-game?

Tags: unity, c#, data-structure

I have created a custom editor to allow me to structure data regarding "actors" in a scripted dialogue. This allows me to conveniently store information about how that "actors" dialogue should be rendered to the screen, when they talk.

However, throughout all my research, I can only find reference to custom editors being used specifically for editor-only functionality. In contrast, I want to be able to derive a data structure specifically for use in-game, much like how you can set custom data via the InputManager inspector that allows you to create customised data structures for referencing input in-game.

I have played around with simply invoking a static reference, but this seems to break the editor. I would also prefer to be able to convert the editor data to a game-specific structure, so as to not have to include the actual editor script in the build. I consider that I might have to save the data to a custom type in my assets, but I am unsure of how I would save / load such a file; everything I find on saving data in this way requires value types, and I need to store references to images, colour and font type.

I was thinking I should be creating a separate script or data file to store the required information; but I require a static file, so a script does not seem like the correct way to store this information as an asset, and I am unsure how I would store non-text information such as font and sprite references.

How do I create a seperate data structure from my custom editor, for specific use in my actual build?

Comment: Usually I derive from ScriptableObject for this kind of content. Then the data file becomes an asset in my project hierarchy, able to cross-reference to and be referenced from other assets, and if I need to load it dynamically I can access it by path like a Resource. Does something like that work for your case?

Comment: @DMGregory, I think it might, and I have some idea how I would create the data file and access it as a resource; I am unsure how I would use it to store references to other assets, which I'm thinking I would need to do for font and sprites.

Comment: That's the great thing about it being an asset you can select in the project hierarchy — it gets an Inspector view just like GameObjects and Components do, so you can expose public or serializable fields to drop your other assets into (if not assigning them via another script or custom editor) :)

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [`ScriptableObject`](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/scriptable-objects)s.

Creating a class which extends ScriptableObject is a way to create a custom kind of asset which can be managed in the project outline like any other asset and is usually edited with a custom editor script.

ScriptableObjects can not exist in a scene on their own. They are always referenced by an actual game object.

So when you have an NPC game object in your game scene, that NPC could have a `NPCController` behaviour with a variable `public NPCDialog dialog`. When `NPCDialog` is a ScriptableObject, you would create a new NPCDialog asset, edit it with your custom editor script, and then drag it from the project outline into the `Dialog` field in the inspector of the NPController of the NPC game object.

Comment: I worked out a lot of that from DMGregorys comment and further research; I guess I am still confused about moving from a custom editor to a physical asset to game-level access. When you say "create NPCDialog asset", do you mean an actual asset in my asset folder? I have played around with trying to physically create an asset in my assets folder, between scripts and text based files, but failed miserably. I think I will have to invest some more time in researching and playing around with `ScriptableObject`, when time allows. Thanks for putting this as an answer, though. +1

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up creating the desired functionality by using a static singleton class, and having my custom editor push and pull the data to an array within this singleton. I am still not convinced it is the best solution; but it is a solution, as far as I have tested.

---

First, I moved my class structure to the game script, so it would still be included in a build. I also include logic to turn the game class into a singleton and overload the `[]` operator for convenient access to the array.

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;

// Basic form of my required structure.
public class ActorListing
{
    public string name;
    public Color colour;
}

// MonoBehaviour structure for storing my actor list in a game object.
public class ActorList : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static ActorList hive;
    public ActorListing[] actors;

    // Setting up ActorList to act as a Singleton.
    private void Awake()
    {
        if(hive == null)
        {
            hive = this;
            DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
        }
        else if(hive != this)
        {
            // I do not want to destroy the game object, as I may be
            // using it for other functionality.
            Destroy(this);
        }
    }

    // Overloading the [] operator so I can directly access actors
    // using actorListing[index].
    public ActorListing this[int index]
    {
        get 
        { 
            return actors[index]; 
        }
        set 
        { 
            actors[index] = value; 
        }
    }
}
```

I then add logic to the custom editor to retrieve reference to the local instance of `ActorList`, and pull the `ActorListing` data directly from `actors`. If neither exist, they are created; we assume that `actors` has not been filled out, at this point.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;

// Editor window for managing the actor list.
public class ActorListEditor : EditorWindow
{
    public List<ActorListing> actors;

    // When the window is opened, pull the actor list from the __GameManager.
    void Awake()
    {
        PullActorList();
    }

    // When the window is closesd, push the actor list to the __GameManager.
    void OnDestroy()
    {
        PushActorList();
    }

    // Increment through the actors in the __GameManager actor array, 
    // and pull each actor listing to the local actors list
    private void PullActorList()
    {
        ActorList actorList = GetActorList();

        actors = new List<ActorListing>();

        for(int actorIndex = 0; actorIndex < actorList.length; actorIndex++)
        {
            actors.Add(actorList[actorIndex]);
        }
    }

    // Increment through the actors, and push each actor listing
    // to the __GameManager actor array.
    private void PushActorList()
    {
        ActorList actorList = GetActorList();

        actorList.actors = new ActorListing[length];

        for(int actorIndex = 0; actorIndex < length; actorIndex++)
        {
            actorList[actorIndex] = actors[actorIndex];
        }
    }

    // Retrieve a reference to the __GameManager actor list;
    // creating one, if one has not already been created.
    private ActorList GetActorList()
    {
        GameObject gameManager = GameObject.Find("__GameManager");

        if(gameManager == null)
        {
            gameManager = new GameObject("__GameManager");
        }

        ActorList actorList = gameManager.GetComponent<ActorList>();

        if(actorList == null)
        {
            actorList = gameManager.AddComponent<ActorList>();
        }

        return actorList;
    }

    /* Additional functions for displaying and managing editor GUI */
}
```

---

This script is still in its early days, so any input is appreciated; but it seems to offer the functionality I require.